# Python - Check if requests received the full page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I use this function in my scripts to request the BeautifoulSoup object of a webpage:

```
def getSoup(url):
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    i = 0
    while i == 0:
        print '(%s) (INFO) Connecting to: %s ...' % (getTime(), url)
        data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        if soup == None:
            print '(%s) (WARN) Received \'None\' BeautifulSoup object, retrying in 5 seconds ...' % getTime()
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            i = 1
    return soup
```

This loops until I receive a valid BeautifulSoup object, but I was thinking that I could also receive an incomplete webpage but still have a valid BeautifulSoup object. I thought of using something like:

```
if '</hml>' in str(data):
    #the page is completly loaded
```

But I don't know if is safe to use it in this way. Is there a safe way to check if a page has been correctly downloaded with requests or BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to check the status code of the request and see if you received a partial content response (206).   List of standard HTTP responses and their definitions are listed [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data + partial_data, 'lxml')
    partial_data = None
    if soup == None:
        print '(%s) (WARN) Received \'None\' BeautifulSoup object, retrying in 5 seconds ...' % getTime()
        time.sleep(5)
elif reponse.status_code == 206:
    # store partial data here
    partial_data += response.data
```